# How to place "offset loopcuts" next to each loopcut at the same time

Tags: loop, looping

[image: loopcuts]
I have divided a solid with a few loopcuts, but, after that, I need to place a couple of "offset loopcuts" for all loops (i.e., see the green lines I added). If I use the command "offset edges" only 2 additional edges appear (you see them highlighted in orange in the upper and bottom sides of the prism). But I want (in this case) to add 6 couples of "offset loopcuts".

Comment: Hi :). You could simply bevel the edges instead. With 3 segments you'll get the same result.

Comment: Génial! Thank you!